# Problem with deplyoing application on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm new to Heroku

I have been trying to deploy my app to Heroku but I'm having an issue which I can't resolve

My build passes and the app gets deployed but there is an error which I can't find nor resolve

I'm not really sure where to look nor what to look for since I'm literally too new to Heroku
Here is my build log

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  12.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.x
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.3
       Bootstrapping npm 6.x (replacing 6.14.6)...
       npm 6.x installed
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules   
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       added 39 packages in 1.246s
-----> Build
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       audited 39 packages in 0.584s       
       1 package is looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       found 0 vulnerabilities
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 23.4M
-----> Launching...
       Released v5
       https://ferit-virtual-classroom.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

And here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ferit-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "publishConfig": { "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/" },
  "author": "JaVolimKatarinu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.1.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "node-fetch-npm": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "engines":{
    "node": "12.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
  "start": "main.js"
}

}
```

I have searched for a potential answer on [Heroku support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type) but without any luck

Thank you for reading and I would be really glad for a helpful answer

EDIT:All  good, I have managed to deploy the app and its working

Thanks for help

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. What's the error? What's the problem?

Comment: I cant find the error, problem is that app builds succesfully and gets deployed on the end, but it wont start

Answer (score 0):

The scripts in package-json file is not properly setup.
There must always be a start command which can be anything to be run in the terminal, but for yours, the script should be

```
 "scripts": {
  "start": "node main.js"
  }
```

**node** keyword is ignored, thats why?

Comment: Nope, still wont start.

Comment: Kindly share github link if possible!

Answer (score 0):

did you add a Procfile ?

```
web: node main.js
```